# Amount of Inserts per minute SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, group-by

I have a table with a column called timestamp (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) and message. How would I display how many messages where sent every minute (not just in an given time).

I've done this but it's for every time. How would I go about changing it
to count the number sent from HH-00:00 to HH:01:00 and so on.

```
SELECT timestamp, COUNT(*)
FROM Messages
GROUP BY timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: I'm thinking you could use `BETWEEN` if you had two filter timestamps.

Comment: Check Hour , Minute function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE(timestamp),MAKETIME(HOUR(timestamp),MINUTE(timestamp),0))
,COUNT(1) 
FROM 
Messages 
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP(DATE(timestamp),MAKETIME(HOUR(timestamp),MINUTE(timestamp),0))
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP(DATE(timestamp),MAKETIME(HOUR(timestamp),MINUTE(timestamp),0))
```

Comment: @JamesCoombes you are comparing apples and oranges (SQL and JavaScript)...

Comment: @JamesCoombes, how do you want the result to be ordered? Ascending or descending?

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz Would it be possible to have to timestamp still as YYY-MM-DD HH-MM:00?

Comment: @JamesCoombes, I've made an update to the code. Try this and tell me if it works.

Comment: This might not work if MySQL has ONLY FULL GROUP BY enabled.

Comment: I think that's the error im getting ------------
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Messages.Messages.Timestamp' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT HOUR(timestamp) AS Hour, 
       MINUTE(timestamp) AS minute, 
       COUNT(*) 
FROM Messages 
GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp), MINUTE(timestamp)
ORDER BY HOUR(timestamp) DESC, MINUTE(timestamp) DESC
```